# shinycssloader keeps loading even after activity is finished

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

```
tabPanel("Call Tab",

                 wellPanel(style = "background: white",
                      wellPanel(style = "background: #ff6666",
                              h4("Case1:EWS&0Count"),
                              h5("Check")
                      ),        

                    formattableOutput("case1.Table")  %>% withSpinner()

                  ),
```

The withSpinner of shinycssloaders package keeps on loading even after the table output is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the dot in your output name (`"case1Table"` instead of `"case1.Table"`)
Please see the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(formattable)


ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("formattableOutput withSpinner"),

    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),

                  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel(
                          "Call Tab",
                          wellPanel(
                              style = "background: white",
                              wellPanel(style = "background: #ff6666",
                                        h4("Case1:EWS&0Count"),
                                        h5("Check")),
                              withSpinner({formattableOutput("case1Table")})
                          )
                      )
                  )))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$case1Table <- renderFormattable({
        formattable(data.frame(replicate(10, runif(10, 0, 10))))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```